# Multiple groups with Linear Quantile Mixed Models

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm trying to fit a linear quantile mixed model with multiple group variables for random effects.

With [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) in R, I can use
`model <- lmer(target ~ feat1 + (1|feat2) + (1|feat3), data)`
which gets me two set of random effects for both `feat2` and `feat3`.

Is it possible to do anything similar for quantile models? Reading through the doc for [lqmm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lqmm/index.html), it seems it can only do one group variable?

Comment: Is your question about the stats methods of building this model, or the code? If stats, it should be moved to [stats.se]; if it's code, it's fine here. Either way it needs a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862)

Comment: Agree wit suggestion to migrate;  this appears to be a package recommendation request. You have found a package that does not meet your needs and you want advice about other packages that might satisfy them. Time for the stats experts at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/ . You definitely need to explain the reasons for this effort and the research question more expansively.

Comment: I'm actually asking if there's an existing package that can achieve this. If not, I can try to move this to the other sites. Thanks!